# How to create 3 new columns out of Product_code,Product_name and avg price in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create a new subquery and add the columns out of it to an already existing table. I want these columns to be set to values of 
1- The product's code
2- The Product's name
3- The avg of the buying price of that product
of course that needs a WHERE condition to set the avg of the price for the product to equal the entry that user gave.

I've already tried to create the subquery, add it to the table and take values out of it to assign it to the sell price as shown in the code below
The main table's name is store2

```
c.execute('''UPDATE  store2 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  Product_Name, AVG(Unit_Buying_Price) 
            FROM    store2 
            GROUP BY Product_Name
        ) average2 ON store2.Product_Name = average2.Product_Name
SET     store2.Unit_Buying_Price = average2.AVG(Unit_Buying_Price)
WHERE   store2.Product_Code = ? ''',(Product_Codev.get()))
```

The new added columns should be in a table called average2
The Buying price is inserted via a textbox by the user 
The new columns should be created at the end of the table for each product code there should be the average of the buying price of that product.
so it would seem like
Product_Name| Avg_Price -----------------
Monitor|100$

and then that 100$ should be assigned to a new column that already exists called Unit_Sell_Price

When I try the code above it gives me this

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FUJITSU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\_
_init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "stores.py", line 155, in submit
    WHERE   store2.Product_Code = ? ''',(Product_Codev.get()))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "INNER": syntax error
```

Comment: Try add a comma in your tuple `(Product_Codev.get(),)`.

Comment: Same error . Didn't work but thanks for your contribution

Comment: SQLite does not support joins in UPDATE statements.

Comment: Is there a way then to take the value of avg for each product without doing this?
Help please I'm really stuck here.Thanks

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. You mention *new added columns* and a table *average2*. Post sample data, expected results and explain what you want.

Comment: I 'm creating a storage system. I want the sell price to be the average of the buying price of the same product. If you have any idea on how to do it please tell me and suppose that I haven't said a thing about my data. I'll recreate it for my code. I'm sorry but if I put sample data It would be too big. I can't narrow it down because I'm not very good at sqlite so please try to come out with an idea that takes the average of the buying price (which is a column already existing) for the same product and assigned to selling value. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the averages in a CTE and update the table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Product_Name, AVG(Unit_Buying_Price) AS AveragePrice 
  FROM store2 
  GROUP BY Product_Name
)
UPDATE store2
SET Unit_Selling_Price = (
  SELECT AveragePrice
  FROM cte
  WHERE Product_Name = store2.Product_Name
);
```

Or without the CTE:

```
UPDATE store2
SET Unit_Selling_Price = (
  SELECT AVG(s.Unit_Buying_Price)
  FROM store2 AS s
  WHERE s.Product_Name = store2.Product_Name
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what does s represent. Is it the new table's name ?
another thing. Sorry I can't understand the CTE example due to the lack of my experience. Thank you a lot I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `s` is the alias of the table store2 inside the subquery to distinguish it from the main table. The CTE provides a query that return all the avaerages. You can find more here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: Oh my god it worked !!! Thank you , thank you. Thanks a ton I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to ask you a question. This edits the whole table to be the new value even in the incoming rows. I want it to update the avg only when outgoing>0 and incoming = 0

Comment: What is incoming and outgoing? I don't see anything like that in your code.